# Android with Xamarin

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've been struggling for some time on this problem, without solving it or finding a solution over the net.

I've basically an `ActionBar` with four tabs, handled through `Fragments`. They contain various parameters, but two of them need to be password protected. My idea was to request the password to the user (I've already a separated activity I use whenever I've to ask for a password), and if it's inserted correctly let the user navigate to the "*protected tabs*", returning him to the tab selected before the password request if it was not correctly typed.

In *Windows* this was achieved through the `Selecting event` of a `tab control` that has the `Cancel property`.
Here's the code I'm using :

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        _passwordInserted = false;
        _pwd = this.Intent.GetStringExtra(ExtraValues.Password);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Parametri);

        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

        AddTab("Stampante", Resource.Drawable.stampa_48, new paramPrinterFragment(), false, 0);
        AddTab("Utility", Resource.Drawable.utility_48, new paramUtilityFragment(), false, 1);
        AddTab("Sync", Resource.Drawable.synchronize, new paramSyncFragment(), true, 2);
        AddTab("Parametri", Resource.Drawable.settings, new paramCommonFragment(), true, 3);
    }

    protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        base.OnStart ();
    }

    void AddTab (string tabText, int iconResourceId, Fragment view, bool reqPassword, int tabIndex)
    {
        var tab = this.ActionBar.NewTab ();

        tab.SetText (tabText);
        tab.SetIcon (iconResourceId);

        // must set event handler before adding tab
        tab.TabSelected += delegate(object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
        {
            _newTab = tabIndex;

            if (reqPassword && !_passwordInserted)
            {
                Intent _password = new Intent(this, typeof(dialogPassword));

                if (_pwd == null)
                    _password.PutExtra(ExtraValues.Password, "");
                else
                    _password.PutExtra(ExtraValues.Password, _pwd.ToString());

                StartActivityForResult(_password, (int)ActivityRequests.Password);
            }
            else
            {
                _lastTab = tabIndex;
                Fragment fragment = this.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.paramFragmentContainer);

                if (fragment != null)
                    e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(fragment);         

                e.FragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.paramFragmentContainer, view);
            }
        };

        tab.TabUnselected += delegate(object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
        {
            e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(view);
        };

        this.ActionBar.AddTab (tab);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode != (int)ActivityRequests.Password)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            return;
        }

        if(clStaticCommon._utilsHandler == null)
            clStaticCommon._utilsHandler = new Handler();

        _passwordInserted = resultCode == Result.Ok;

        clStaticCommon._utilsHandler.PostAtFrontOfQueue(SelectCallback);
    }

    private void SelectCallback()
    {
        ActionBar.SetSelectedNavigationItem(_passwordInserted ? _newTab : _lastTab);
        ActionBar.SelectTab(ActionBar.GetTabAt(_passwordInserted ? _newTab : _lastTab));

    }
```

I'm currently working on Android 4.4
Thanks.
Rodolfo.

PS: forgot to mention.... This code works, but when you select a protected page for the first time, and insert the correct password, the tab isn't displayed. You have to select another tab and then go back.

PS2: solved modifyng as reported below the TabSelected event. The tab remains visible under the password request dialog, but it's not so important.

```
        tab.TabSelected += delegate(object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
        {
            _newTab = tabIndex;

            Fragment fragment = this.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.paramFragmentContainer);

            if (fragment != null)
                e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(fragment);         

            e.FragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.paramFragmentContainer, view);

            if (reqPassword && !_passwordInserted)
            {
                Intent _password = new Intent(this, typeof(dialogPassword));

                if (_pwd == null)
                    _password.PutExtra(ExtraValues.Password, "");
                else
                    _password.PutExtra(ExtraValues.Password, _pwd.ToString());

                StartActivityForResult(_password, (int)ActivityRequests.Password);
            }
            else
                _lastTab = tabIndex;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Xamarin Employees Directory demo app (https://github.com/xamarin/prebuilt-apps/blob/master/EmployeeDirectory/EmployeeDirectory.Android/BaseActivity.cs), they use the resume event to load the login activity if necessary.

```
    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume ();

        if (LoginViewModel.ShouldShowLogin (Android.Application.LastUseTime)) {
            var intent = new Intent (this, typeof (LoginActivity));
            intent.SetFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```